# finding the maximum scroll position of a page

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have made the body of the page 200% tall so that it fits on a screen twice. Using javascript I am making it keep scrolling to the top or bottom when you scroll. For this, I need to find out the lowest scroll point of the page on any browser or screen size so that it stops when it gets there.

No JQuery please.
Thank you.

My code: (it is still being put together so needs a bit of work)

```
function getScrollXY() {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
        // Netscape
        x = window.pageXOffset;
        y = window.pageYOffset;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
        // DOM
        x = document.body.scrollLeft;
        y = document.body.scrollTop;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
        // IE6 standards compliant mode
        x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    return [x, y];
}

function scrollup() {
    if (xy[1] > 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0,-100);
        setTimeout(scrollup,200);
    } else {
        null;
    }
}

function scrolldown() {
    if (xy[1] < ) {
        window.scrollBy(0,100);
        setTimeout(scrolldown,200);
    } else {
        null;
    }
}

function dothescroll() {
    var xy = getScrollXY();
    var y = xy[1];
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (xy[1] > y) {
            scrollup();
        } else {
            scrolldown();
        }
    },200);
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is the cross browser compatible version:

```
var limit = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, 
                   document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );
```

Comment: if you then minus limit by window.innerHeight that is the maximum scroll position.x

Comment: Not so far the truth :
var limit = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,  document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight) - window.innerHeight;

Comment: On Mac Chrome, if there is a x-axis scroll bar, this and you set `window.scrollY` what Jordan suggests, this will be a few pixels from the true bottom of the page

Comment: You are an absolute life saver. Been looking far and wide for a solution.

Answer (score 27):

While this is not part of any specification, you could try `window.scrollMaxY`.

> Returns the maximum number of pixels that the document can be scrolled vertically.
>   **https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollMaxY**

---

Fallback if unavailable:

```
var scrollMaxY = window.scrollMaxY || (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)
```

Note, `documentElement` isn't always the scrolling element (some browsers use `body` instead). The solution is the new [`scrollingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement) property, which *returns a reference to the Element that scrolls the document*. It is specified, but still a working draft.

Comment: window.scrollMaxY isn't supported in Chrome

Comment: This property is now non-standard and not on a standards track, so it won't work in many 
 browsers

Answer (score 17):

```
var limit = document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;
// document.body.offsetHeight = computed height of the <body>
// window.innerHeight = available vertical space in the window
```

Compare `xy[1] < limit`

**Note:** You might need to increase the value by margin and/or padding of the body. You can also try using `clientHeight` instead of `offsetHeight`.

Comment: not quite perfect sorry, it wasn't cross browser compatible. I will post it under this:

Comment: @Neil - I didn't quite get your last comment. please share the issues you've found with this.

Comment: I have posted as a seperate answer on this post a cross browser friendly version.x

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on the solutions above and what I use in 2022.

AKA `scrollMaxY`

```js
const scrollMaxValue = () => {
  const body = document.body;
  const html = document.documentElement;

  const documentHeight = Math.max(
    body.scrollHeight,
    body.offsetHeight,
    html.clientHeight,
    html.scrollHeight,
    html.offsetHeight
  );

  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

  return documentHeight - windowHeight;
};
```

```
scrollMaxValue()
```

Answer (score -1):

window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

this will work..