# How to adjust a Greensock.js tween based on browser scroll y position rather than by the time?

Tags: javascript, tween, gsap

How would I go about adjusting the time manually based on the scroll position? What might that look like? To basically 'scroll' the tween? So that the tween reacts to the scrolling mouse's Y position rather than just trigger and execute based on a preset time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Tahir's answer is correct and sufficient, there's a lot of unnecessary code to show the example.

A more concise snippet is:

```
var max_scroll = document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;

win.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var scroll_perc = parseFloat(Math.min(window.pageYOffset / max_scroll, 1).toFixed(2));

    TweenMax.to(tl, 0, {
        progress: scroll_perc
    });
});

var tl = new TimelineMax({paused: true});
// the rest of your timeline....
```

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, here is what you'll need to do:

1. You will need **TimelineMax** for sequencing your animations. Place
   your animations in `TimelineMax` as you like them to be.
2. You'll need to figure out the maximum scroll position your `window` can scroll up to, beforehand. (This can also be re-calculated on browser resize as well but I haven't taken this into account in my example below). You can figure out with the
   help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698713/3344111). Also read the comments on that answer.
3. Upon scroll, you'll need to convert the current scroll position of
   your window object into percentage that is: `var currentScrollProgress=window.scrollY/maxScroll;` such that your `currentScrollProgress` should always be between `0` and `1`.
4. `TimelineMax` has a `progress()` method which takes values ranging
   from `0` and `1` where `0` being the initial state of the animations
   and `1` being the final state. Feed this `currentScrollProgress`
   into it and you're done.
5. OR, you can **tween** the `timeline` itself that is: `TweenMax.to(timeline,scrollTweenDuration,{progress:currentScrollProgress,ease:ease});`.

Code used in my example is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div { width: 100%; height: 60px; margin: 2px 0; }
div:nth-child(odd) { background: #cc0; }
div:nth-child(even) { background: #0cc; }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/*global TweenMax, TimelineMax,Power2*/
var myDIVs=document.querySelectorAll('div'),numDIVs=myDIVs.length;
var timeline=new TimelineMax({paused:true}),duration=.4,ease=Power2.easeOut,staggerFactor=.1,scrollTweenDuration=.4;
var scrollTimeout=null,scrollTimeoutDelay=20,currentScrollProgress=0;
var maxScroll=Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,document.body.offsetHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight,document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.offsetHeight)-window.innerHeight; //see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698713/3344111]
function init(){
    initTimeline();
    listenToScrollEvent();
    onScroll();
}
function initTimeline(){
    for(var i=0; i<numDIVs; i+=1){ timeline.fromTo(myDIVs[i],duration,{opacity:0},{opacity:1,ease:ease},i*staggerFactor); }
}
function listenToScrollEvent(){
    (window.addEventListener)?window.addEventListener('scroll',debounceScroll,false):window.attachEvent('onscroll',debounceScroll);
}
function debounceScroll(){
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    scrollTimeout=setTimeout(onScroll,scrollTimeoutDelay);
}
function onScroll(){
    currentScrollProgress=roundDecimal(window.scrollY/maxScroll,4);
    //timeline.progress(currentScrollProgress); // either directly set the [progress] of the timeline which may produce a rather jumpy result
    TweenMax.to(timeline,scrollTweenDuration,{progress:currentScrollProgress,ease:ease}); // or tween the [timeline] itself to produce a transition from one state to another i.e. it looks smooth
}
function roundDecimal(value,place){ return Math.round(value*Math.pow(10,place))/Math.pow(10,place); }
//
init();
```

Here is the [resulting jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/hhfw4bdr/). Hope it helps.

T

Comment: Thank you Tahir! Very awesome.