# Can i use a percentage as a value in scrolltop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I'm pretty new to HTML in general. I have the following code and I was wondering if there is any way of using a percentage instead of a fixed value. I have searched but I couldn't find a simple solution.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 445 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1425 ) { 
        nav.addClass("f-nav");
    } else { 
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
    }
```

Basically what I want is the class to be removed after scrolling past 80% of the page, instead of after 1425px so that it also works properly if the window size is modified.

Comment: When the page is smaller than the windows size you can't scroll. So I think you mean after 80% of scrolling.
Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688595/finding-the-maximum-scroll-position-of-a-page to calculate what the max scrollTop is. Then you can check if `scrollTop > maxScrollTop * 0.8`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the doc, [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) expects a number which represents position in pixel.

But you can calculate when scroll reaches 80% with, for example, something like

Pseudo-code:

```
if ((this.scrollTop + this.height) / content.height >= .8){
// do something
}
```

See the working snippet below for example

```js
$("#container").scroll(function () { 
    if (($(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height())/$("#content").height() >= .8) { 
        $("#content").addClass("scrolled");
     }else{
       $("#content").removeClass("scrolled");
     }
     });
```

```css
#container{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow:auto;
}

#content{
  width:80%;
  height:1000px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
#content.scrolled{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So it should look like this?  $(window).scroll(function () { 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 445 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1425 ) { 
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
        if ($(this).scrollTop()/$(this).height() >= .8){
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");}
        }

Comment: whoops my bad, can't press enter on a comment. But basically changing the "else" for what you said, right?

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for but it does solve my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update! I ended up using `$(document).height()` instead of scrolltop, because it allowed me to introduce a percentage easily. So my code ended up looking like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 445) { 
        nav.addClass("f-nav");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(document).height()*0.64) 
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
    }       
});
```

Anyways, thanks for the help and I hope someone can find this useful!